# Use variables in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, variables, dockerfile

I am trying to use variables inside a Dockerfile. I don't understand why the occurrence $MyVariable is never replaced by the value.

I build my image using:

```bash
docker build --build-arg PYTHON_VERSION=python-3.8.8.amd64 -t succeeds .
```

In my dockerfile I have the following code :

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=python-3.8.1.amd64
ENV PYTHON=C:\$PYTHON_VERSION

RUN echo $PYTHON_VERSION
RUN echo ${PYTHON_VERSION}
RUN echo PYTHON_VERSION
```

The shell respectively print:

```
$PYTHON_VERSION
${PYTHON_VERSION}
PYTHON_VERSION
```

The documentation suggests:

> An ARG declared before a FROM is outside of a build stage, so it can’t
> be used in any instruction after a FROM. To use the default value of
> an ARG declared before the first FROM use an ARG instruction without a
> value inside of a build stage:
>
> ```
> ARG VERSION=latest FROM
> $VERSION 
> ARG VERSION 
> RUN echo $VERSION > image_version
> ```

But I am clearly not getting the same result. Shall I add something in the docker command to use the variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to know that ARG is not available in the container. While ENV is available in the container.
Please see this good diagram from [here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-vs-env/):
[image]

So in your case you need to use the ENV name and not the ARG name like this:

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=python-3.8.1.amd64
ENV PYTHON=$PYTHON_VERSION

RUN echo $PYTHON
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood that but what I want to do is use a variable ARG to execute a command with RUN. For example I have the ARG test and I want to run something with it like RUN myCommand $test. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: @Teddy - sure, you can do it simply by copy the ARG value into the ENV value and use the ENV in your RUN. Like this: `ARG A=something` `ENV A=$A` `RUN myCommand $A`

Comment: Thanks ! I use %A% instead of $A and it works for me ☺