# Dockerfile: ENTRYPOINT doesn't expand ARG/ENV variable

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I'm using CentOS.7 in a container (because I have to) and need to install some RedHat Software Collection packages to up-version a couple of tools.  This involves running `source scl_source enable <package>` to set up the environment, which I'm doing using an ENTRYPOINT script. Here's what I have in my Dockerfile, and it works...

```
ENV ENTRYPOINT="/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh"
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > ${ENTRYPOINT}; \
    chmod +x ${ENTRYPOINT}

# we need later Git for Visual Studio Code
RUN yum -y install rh-git227; \
    echo "source scl_source enable rh-git227" >> ${ENTRYPOINT}

# we need later python for Visual Studio Code
RUN yum -y install rh-python38-python-devel; \
    echo "source scl_source enable rh-python38" >> ${ENTRYPOINT}

# finish off the extrypoint script to run whatever needs running
RUN echo 'env|sort' >> ${ENTRYPOINT}; \
    echo 'echo ARGV="$@"' >> ${ENTRYPOINT}; \
    echo 'exec "$@"' >> ${ENTRYPOINT}
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

When I start the container using `docker run -it container /bin/bash --login` then the entrypoint.sh script is run and is passed the original command line (`/bin/bash --login`). All good.

However, it bugs me having to repeat the script name in the ENTRYPOINT command, but doing something "obvious" like `ENTRYPOINT [ ${ENTRYPOINT} ]` doesn't work, even if I change ENV to ARG in the definition.  It appears to me that Docker requires a literal string in `ENTRYPOINT [...]`.

I also tried `ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "-c", ${ENTRYPOINT} ]` using ENV but using this form doesn't pass the command line through from `docker run`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker ENTRYPOINT shell form with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062680/docker-entrypoint-shell-form-with-parameters)

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484814/use-variables-in-dockerfile

Comment: I'd just get rid of the `ENTRYPOINT` environment variable.  You might find this easier to write and maintain if you `COPY` the script from the host system into the image, instead of building it up line by line using `RUN echo` commands, and this will also limit the number of times you need to repeat the filename.

Comment: @Paolo yes, given the lack of a usable Dockerfile variable, using the shell form of `ENTRYPOINT` to expand the environment variable and pass in the `CMD` array is a very readable workaround. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev no, that answer doesn't help, but thanks for trying.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't want to `COPY` from the host filesystem because the contents of that file would be hidden from the `yum install` commands that go with it. And leaving that aside I'd still have to write the file path twice, once in the COPY and once in the ENTRYPOINT command, so good program practise says I should define the file path once, in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use "shell" form

```
ENTRYPOINT ${ENTRYPOINT} "$0" "$@"
```

which Docker converts to "array" form

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "${ENTRYPOINT} \"$0\" \"$@\"" ]
```

The shell substitutes $0 and $@ for the parameters appearing after the command_string, which are the contents of the Dockerfile CMD array (or the parameters passed to `docker run`, which override this).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75063327/232452 for a full explanation.